# Some nodes won't appear in HBox

Tags: javafx, nodes, vbox, hbox, borderpane

I am working on a Yahtzee game just to develop my programming skills and I can't seem to get all the Labels and Radio Buttons to appear in the HBox. Here is all the relevant code:

```
public class Main extends Application{

Label diceRoll1 = new Label("1");
Label diceRoll2 = new Label("2");
Label diceRoll3 = new Label("3");
Label diceRoll4 = new Label("4");
Label diceRoll5 = new Label("5");

RadioButton holdRButton1 = new RadioButton("Hold");
RadioButton holdRButton2 = new RadioButton("Hold");
RadioButton holdRButton3 = new RadioButton("Hold");
RadioButton holdRButton4 = new RadioButton("Hold");
RadioButton holdRButton5 = new RadioButton("Hold");

Button rollDice = new Button("Roll!");

Stage window;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{
    VBox diceRoll1Layout = new VBox(5);
    diceRoll1Layout.getChildren().addAll(diceRoll1, holdRButton1);

    VBox diceRoll2Layout = new VBox(5);
    diceRoll2Layout.getChildren().addAll(diceRoll2, holdRButton2);

    VBox diceRoll3Layout = new VBox(5);
    diceRoll3Layout.getChildren().addAll(diceRoll3, holdRButton3);

    VBox diceRoll4Layout = new VBox(5);
    diceRoll4Layout.getChildren().addAll(diceRoll4, holdRButton4);

    VBox diceRoll5Layout = new VBox(5);
    diceRoll5Layout.getChildren().addAll(diceRoll5, holdRButton5);

    HBox diceRolls = new HBox(5);
    diceRolls.getChildren().addAll(diceRoll1Layout,diceRoll2Layout,diceRoll3Layout,
            diceRoll4Layout,diceRoll5Layout, rollDice);

    BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
    rootPane.setBottom(diceRolls);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 400, 500);
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Yahtzee!");
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

}
}
```

But for some reason whenever I run the code only diceRoll1, diceRoll2, holdRButton1, holdRButton2 and rollDice appear in the window. They're all coded the same so I don't know why they don't all appear. I tried setting them to visible and it made no difference. Am I missing something?

Comment: This works fine for me. However I strongly recommend you don't instantiate the controls in the initializer (i.e. inline where you declare them). Initialize them in the `start()` method. (You can still declare them as fields. However you probably don't need to, and can just declare them as local variables in `start()`.)

Comment: The reason I have them declared there is because they are all used by several methods below that I didn't include here. It's just easier than having to pass all the variables I need into every method. I may just copy my code into a new project and see if it works there.

Comment: You can still declare them there, just don't initialize them there.

Comment: Update: I rebuilt the whole thing from scratch in a new project and I haven't had any of the same problems. That's what I get from trying to do things the easy way.